# Right way to type as "Any"

Tags: godot, gdscript

Let's say I'm using gdscript static typing and for one function parameter I don't know in advance what I'm going to get. That's what `typing.Any` is for in python. How do I do it with gdscript?

It seems that `Variant` is not a valid type and I'm not sure about using `Object` for that purpose (since it could be a built-in)

**edit**
Leaving the type blank obviously works, but the docs has a specific section called [typed-or-dynamic-stick-to-one-style](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html#typed-or-dynamic-stick-to-one-style), and since we're already kinda short on good practices using gdscript I'd rather find another way

Any idea?

Comment: I believe you just have to leave the type blank. Could you explain why the type is unknown to the function please?

Comment: Yep, I can leave the type blank but that kinda goes against the "duck-typing or typed, but not both" mantra. As for why the type must be blank, it's mainly because the function is not mature right now, it can accept a long list of types and, since this list is probably going to change over time I don't want to maintain both the function body and parameter long list of possible types.

Comment: Ah OK, I haven't used the Variant type in GDScript before. I had a quick look online and according to the latest documentation the ```Variant``` type can be used to store "almost" any data type... When you said that ```Variant``` is not a valid type, what were you trying to store into it please? I'm very curious to know as I'm sure I'll also run into this problem eventually.

Answer (score 5):

As of Godot 3.2, [GDScript does not feature a `Variant` or `any` type hint yet](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/26228). However, you can still use the `Object` type hint if you expect a variable to hold any object (or `null`, as Object is nullable by design). `Object` may not hold primitive types like `int` or `bool` though.

Therefore, you should just leave out the type hint for now.